# Decoupling in Class and in Project other than IoC & Dependency Injection (java)

Tags: java, decoupling

What other (besides IoC & Dependency Injection) decoupling patterns and practices could be used inside of an object and than between objects (in project).

If you could post samples if any in Java that would be awesome.

I'm working with spring and I'm running into situations where beans just won't cut it. So I just want to see alternative options. Mainly it is with integration of 3th party APIs that are written with very little consideration when comes to OOP. The re-usability of some of the API code is just atrocious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aspect Oriented programming. Spring also supports it http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop.html

Comment: AOP is mainly used for cross cutting features (timing, logging, exception handling, etc). You can take a look at this post ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459974/java-remove-repeated-try-catch-finally-boilerplate-from-dao/4459997#4459997

Comment: This is the more current link to AOP -> http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html .